# Is there a such thing as a Homogenous Monomial

Tags: polynomials

Is there a word for a monomial in only one variable?  Let me explain: consider the homogenous polynomial

$x_1^5 + x_1^4 x_2 + \cdots + x_2^5$.

I there a term for the two terms at the ends? $x_1^5$ and $x_2^5$.  I feel like the term should be "the homogenous monomials of the homogenous polynomial" but this sounds kinda funky.

Comment: Every monomial is homogeneous. I don't know a term, although you could just say that these monomials involve one variable only.

Answer (score 1):

It may have no commonly used name but they are the terms of
the [Power sum symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial)
which are a special case of
[Homogeneous polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial).